# Magento 2: Migrating a Module's system.xml Configuration

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml, conversion

Are there any automated tools for converting a Magento 1 module's `system.xml` file to the new Magento 2 format?  I took a look at the existing [code-migration](https://github.com/magento/code-migration) tools, and they don't (seem to?) do this for you.

Comment: i tried but did not work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in progress. Right now we focused on controller migration but configuration will come.

Comment: "controlled" or "controller"?